# Disable Landscape mode in AMP site

Tags: javascript, amp-html

Since we can't add custom JavaScript or event listeners in AMP, is there any possible way to block landscape mode in an AMP site?

Answer (score 1):

**According to me you can not change OS behaviour via a website**

You can use css media query tricks, In landscape mode show the portrait view by using css

```
<style amp-custom>
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```